# JQuery Droppable/Sortable/Accordion: additional div for droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need some assist with my current problem. I have a listview in my aps.net page which is filled with stuff and looks like this (the one on the top):

[listview with dragged item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ivNC.png)

I also have items in this listview which I can drag-n-drop. Doing this with the `droppable` and `sortable` provided by `JQuery`. The initialization stuff looks like this:
[init stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXffX.png)

My problem is as soon as I leave the `h3 header` in the listview items like its in the first picture (the bottom one) and the drag the item onto the white area, the `accordion` will close itself. I want the `accordion` stay open after I left the `droparea` (the grey headers) and enter the whitearea. Also to mention: every listview item is one accordion so for example if I have 3 items there are are 3 accordions (for each `.accEpa`)

My code looks like this but way more complicated:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="accordion">
    <div id="wrapper2" class="accordion">
        <div id="FirstListViewItem" class="accEpa"> //<--- for the accordion
            <h3 id="header" class="ui-accordion-header">//<--- for the droppable
                Some Text
            </h3> 
            <div id="xx" class="accordion">
                <ul class="sortable"> //<--- for the sortable
                    <li>
                     First Listview Nested Item
                    </li>
                    <li>
                     Second Listview Nested Item
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66aj8h4r/) <-- Here a try to reproduce the problem. If you take a file from your pc and move it over the "Test" accordions they will open and like i want but as I drag the file over the listitems within the accordion it goes crazy

Comment: Fixed your fiddle and am unable to replicate the issue you described. https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xno25o15/

Comment: Not able to find one good solution. But this may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xno25o15/7/

Comment: @Twisty thank you for fixing the fiddle :) your solution is great but is it possible to open the accordion as soon as I dragg an item over it and as soon as i leave the accordion to close it?